# Riddle similar to the 100 prisoners riddle, but different

Tags: modular-arithmetic, puzzle

The riddle goes like this:

$\qquad$ There are $100$ prisoners standing in line, each with a number on their back. The numbers are all different, and range from $1$ to $101$ (i.e. one number is missing). The person in the back of the line can see all 99 prisoners ahead of him's numbers. The prisoner in the front of the line sees no numbers. Starting with the prisoner in the back, each prisoner must shout the number on their own back, but *each number can be said aloud only once*.

$\qquad$The first prisoner clearly only has a $50$% chance of guessing his number correctly. However, once he has guessed his number correctly, the remaining 99 prisoners have a $100$% chance of correctly guessing the number on their backs.

What is their strategy to achieve this?

**Update:**

I have been given a hint that the solution "does not just involve modulo sums." There is more to the solution than just a modular trick.

Comment: To be clear, I don't know the solution. I was given the riddle and am seeing if anyone else knows it.

Comment: So each prisoner can shout multiple numbers? What  do you mean by "once he has guessed his number correctly"? Or should it be "**If** he guess his number correctly"?

Comment: So you are saying if the first one guesses his numbers correctly, other ones will be able to guess their and be 100% sure about it? So you are assuming they heard his correct guess, and now person $99$ knows all numbers in front of him, including the number that the person $100$ behind him guessed correctly? This leaves two numbers unknown for person $99$, his own and the missing one. Doesn't this leave him in the same situation as the person $100$? And what do you mean "once he guessed his number..." How many guesses then they have? I think you need to be more clear about certain things here.

Comment: @Matta, not necessarily -- the first prisoner can base which of her 2 options she picks based on which numbers she sees in front of her. This way, she can communicate information to the other prisoners. (In fact, with 2 players and 3 numbers, the game is quite easy: the first prisoner shouts the number she sees in front of her, minus 1 modulo 3, and the prisoner in front of her can invert that.)

Comment: @Ove yes, he only gets one guess to shout his number so it should be corrected to **if**.

Comment: @Mees has the right idea I think. Do you know how it works then when there are 101 numbers and 100 prisoners? Do you the lower or higher number you don't see in front of you and do something modulo 101? I can't figure out how to go about it once it gets more complex than with two people.

Answer (score 3):

The back prisoner imagines another behind with the missing number.  He then guesses the number that will make the list an even permutation of the numbers $1$ to $101$.  The person in front of him (assuming the first guess is correct) knows all the numbers but two and can select the one that makes the permutation even.  Each prisoner in turn has just two choices (assuming the previous shouts are correct) and one of those will make the permutation even.

Second solution:  back person shouts the number on the front person.  As he has failed to state his number correctly, there is no requirement that the others are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a strategy that works if the whole bunch of people are allowed to make at most one error (a reasonable assumption, I think, given that no matter what strategy he uses, the last guy gets the answer correct with probability at most 0.5): have the last guy shout out the sum modulo 101 of the two missing numbers. Then every person in front of him will have to choose between 3 missing numbers (having eliminated the ones that have already been shouted out), and they just need to see which two of the three numbers, when summed, give the one that the last person shouted out. This leaves them with only one possibility, which they shout out. Note: this only works because for any 3 distinct numbers (a,b,c), the sum of any two distinct pairs of them cannot be the same (even if the sum is modulo some integer).

Comment: The odds of the sum modulo 101 of the two missing numbers being one of the two numbers not that the last person doesn't see is very unlikely, though. A prisoner isn't allowed to say a number that he can see in front of him.

Comment: @BrianW: : "A prisoner isn't allowed to say a number that he can see in front of him. " was not part of the problem.  I was trying a solution where the back person would say a number known to be wrong in some cases. He would always shout $1$, even if somebody else had that number.  It failed, but I didn't think it outside the rule.

Comment: My apologies for not including that in the original post. I have edited it so that it now includes that information.

Answer (score 0):

There are many prisoner riddles and it is unclear to me which is the base version you are referring to. In one of the versions I know (which is more general), the statement is different, but the solution also works for your question since it is a special case. It involves what I believe you call "modulo sums", and therefore I am wondering if that version is the base version you are referring to. That said, at the end of this answer I explore other interpretations of the problem statement as well...

Let $x_k$ be the number on the back of prisoner $k\in\{0,\cdots,N-1\}$, and let $s_k$ be the number shouted. The $N+1$ numbers are permutations of $\{0,\cdots,N\}$ (I start with a 0 index instead of 1 as in your statement to alleviate adjustments to the modulo arithmetic, but the problem is equivalent). The strategy is then as follows:

1. the first prisoner sacrifices themself in order to give all the other prisoners the information they need by shouting the modulo N+1 of the sum of numbers they see ahead of themselves, i.e.:
   $$
   s_0=\left(\sum\limits_{j>1}x_j\right)\mod (N+1)
   $$
2. the second prisoner now knows that:
   $$
   \left(x_1+\sum\limits_{j>1}x_j\right)\mod (N+1)=s_0
   $$
   and thus solves for $x_1$
3. prisoner $k$ will solve
   $$
   \left(x_k+\sum\limits_{0<j<k}s_j+\sum\limits_{j>k}x_j\right)\mod (N+1)=s_0
   $$
   because, starting with $j=1$, they know that $s_j=x_j$

To convince yourself that this works, you can check out this [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1clYhmsHeX-mWI-HtXUkjkdxfQmFLok8tS5Nrn2glFNs/edit#gid=0) I made. Aside from the randomization button which calls a script, all the logic is implemented as formulas and you can check that each prisoner only uses the knowledge at their disposal, namely the previous shouts (if any) and the numbers on the backs of those after them. (In particular, for those who do not want to trust the script, or if the script is not active for some reason, you can simply change the random values by hand.)

I am a bit confused by your statement "each number can be said aloud only once", and given the comments and how old your question is, I surmise that this was added to avoid prisoners having a second chance to say a number if they were wrong the first time. (This was suggested in one of the answers, but the riddle is then trivial since all players can solve for sure in 2 guesses given that there are only 2 unknowns each time.) That said, if you did mean that a specific number could only be called once, then the above solution can be tweaked by having the first prisoner shout $s_0^*=s_0+(N+1)$, which is a number which cannot be on the back of any prisoner.

If, on the other hand, the statement of the problem is that the first prisoner only has the choice between two numbers, namely either the number on their back or the missing number, then I would ask you to double check the problem statement:

- let's study the case for prisoner $k>0$. Supposing all the prisoners, except the first, were able to correctly guess $s_j=x_j, \forall 0<j<k$ with certainty, then $k$ is left with two numbers unaccounted for: either $x^*$ and $x_k$ if $s_0=x_0$, or $x_0$ and $x_k$ if $s_0=x^*$.
- either way, the information as to which one to choose must be encoded somehow, but the previous prisoners do not encode anything: they simply chose $s_j=x_j$, which helps for book-keeping but does not say anything about those two values.
- the only prisoner capable of encoding that information is the first one, and they can do that if they have a large enough "language" to encode that information (such as in the first portion of this answer, in which there are $N+1$ values to choose from to express that information).
- however, if the choice for that prisoner is binary between $x^*$ and $x_0$, there is only one bit of information that can be transmitted. That can help prisoner 2 make the correct choice, but it is insufficient to help all the following prisoners.

This, of course, leaves the door open to some "hacks", such as passing information in other ways (e.g. voice inflexion, etc.), but my impression is that the correct statement is in fact the one for which the first portion of this answer provides a solution.